# Typescript pagination

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, pagination, ngfor

I am trying to create a pagination functionality for an Angular project and I have to do this only with typescript.
Task: paginate an array, number of objects displayed per page is 15.
My declarations are:

```
  PAGE_SIZE: number = 15;
  total: number = this.booksArray.length;
  pageNumber: number = 1;
  pageBooks!: BookModel[];
  numberOfPages: number = Math.ceil(this.total/this.PAGE_SIZE);
  currentPage!: number;
```

Total will be the number of the objects within the array, pageNumber is initialized to 1.
pageBooks should be a subarray of the booksArray, and it is the array to be displayed on the page.
Getting the books to display on the page is done through the following method, however if I use the pageBooks variable in the *ngFor html it won't yield anything; instead I use the full method name and arg.(1st problem)

```
getPageBooks(pageNumber: number) {
    var trimLeft: any = (pageNumber - 1) * this.PAGE_SIZE;
    var trimRight: any = pageNumber * this.PAGE_SIZE;
    (trimRight < this.booksArray[this.total - 1]) ? pageNumber * this.PAGE_SIZE : this.booksArray[(this.total - 1)];
    const pageBooks = this.booksArray.slice(trimLeft, trimRight);
    return pageBooks;
  }
```

Console logging in the ngOnInit() returns an undefined or 0, which halts my progress(2nd problem).
I have also prepared several methods to add to my html as pagination events:

```
    showPage(index) {
    let displayedPage =  this.getPageBooks(index);
    this.displayBooks(displayedPage);
    this.currentPage = index;
  }

  showFirstPage() {
    this.showPage(1);
  }

  showLastPage() {
    this.showPage(numberOfPages);
  }

  showNextPage() {
    let pageToDisplay = this.currentPage + 1;
    this.currentPage = pageToDisplay; 
    this.showPage(this.currentPage);
  }

  showPreviousPage() {
    let pageToDisplay = this.currentPage - 1;
    this.currentPage = pageToDisplay; 
    this.showPage(this.currentPage);
  }
```

Could someone please help and advise on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Show your ngOnInit method.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz  `ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addedBookServie.addedBookAction$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.isAddMobile = false;
    });
    this.addedBookServie.addedBookAction$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.booksArray.push(data);
    });
    this.isMobile$ = this.resizeService.isMobile$;
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe((books) => {
      this.booksArray = books;
      this.getPageBooks(this.pageNumber);
    });`